# How to generate a formatted document (.doc, .pdf) from a list item in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I would like to be able to select a list item in SharePoint and then generate a nicely-formatted document from the list item's data.

For example, say I have a SharePoint List of "candidates", with fields for 'name', 'address', 'summary', 'job1', 'job2', etc., and I want to generate a resume for a selected candidate.  I'd like to match up fields on the listitem with fields in a document template.

Please note that 'resume' is just an example, I'm not looking for a 3rd party tool unless it is generic enough to match listitem fields to document templates other than resumes.

I imagine something like this could be set up with SQL Server Reporting Services, but I'm not too familiar with that.  Should I investigate that option, or are there better alternatives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some people use the [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) library to populate a fillable PDF with list item fields using a custom action.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this post: [Inserting SharePoint List data into a PDF document using a workflow](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/09/inserting-sharepoint-list-data-into-pdf.html)?